# Vue router beforeRouteEnter - after refreshing the page, the button name disappears

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods, vue-router, beforerouteenter

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'TEST',
   data() {
    return {
      prevRoute: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    goBack() {
      return this.$router.go(-1);
    },
  },
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
      vm.prevRoute = from.name
      console.log(from.name)
    })
  },
}
</script>
```

```html
<template> 
 <div>
  <button @click="goBack" class="back">{{ prevRoute }}</button>
 </div>
</template>
```

*Vue router beforeRouteEnter - after refreshing the page, the button text {{ prevRoute }} disappears. What other ways are there to display text in the button of the previous page?*

Comment: There are no ways. After refreshing current page is the first navigated route. Just output "Back" in case there's no name.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible at all, your `from` route will be always empty on refresh.
The best approach I can figure out is by storing your route `from.name` in your localStorage and set that item only if `from.name` exists

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    if (from.name) localStorage.setItem('from_route', from.name)
    next()
},
```

Then in your mounted hook set the `prevRoute` value as per localStorage item

```
mounted () {
    this.from_route = localStorage.getItem('from_route')
},
```

Of course, you will face the same issue if someone shares you a link and you are not coming from any other page.